# Taglib 1.8 on windows 7 is not working properly like windows XP

Tags: qt, taglib

I compiled taglib 1.8 using Mingw succesfully, then i integrated it into a Qt project.
The purpuse is to remove ID3 Tag from mp3 files.

This code :

```
void MainWindow::removeTagFromFile(QByteArray &fileContent)
{
    TagLib::ByteVector byteVector(fileContent.constData());
    TagLib::ID3v2::FrameFactory *frame = TagLib::ID3v2::FrameFactory::instance();
    TagLib::IOStream *vectorStream = new TagLib::ByteVectorStream(byteVector);
    TagLib::MPEG::File file(vectorStream, frame);
    file.strip();
    file.save();
}
```

Compile and works fine on XP.
Compile and doesn't work as expected on Windows 7.
Taking the ".exe compiled on XP" to seven do not solve the problem.

is it weird ? i'm afraid that this is a bug in Taglib, does it make sense ?
Any idea or an explanation is welcome,
Thanks in advance.

You can download the project [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4oIPD6jAmQOS3ZhMXdNenRoWGM)

I'm writing a tutorial in french about details of compilation and integration into a Qt project, i'll write one in english if there is interested people.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally it's not question of XP or Seven, it's about codecs installed on your computer.

There is a simple solution, you don't need to remove ID3 Tag from mp3 files to get them readable by Phonon, you need just to install K-Lite Codecs.

Explanation :
Phonon backend use DirectShow on Windows to read mp3 files.
The K-Lite Codec Pack is a collection of DirectShow filters, VFW/ACM codecs, and tools. Codecs and DirectShow filters are needed for encoding and decoding audio and video formats.

installing K-Lite solve the problem of Phonon with some mp3 files.

I hope this will save someone out there who suffer from phonon with mp3 files on windows.